# SSRS - Set param to be the time right now but on a different date

Tags: reporting-services

I was asked to create an SSRS Report, but taking the live sales of today and compare it to sales the exact same time as a date to be named later.  For example, "How are we doing compared to this time on last Saturday?"  The user would simply pick the date, and the query would calculate sales for both Today() and @BusinessDate, from the start of the business until Today()'s time.

I am sure I can do the query, but I don't know how to set a query parameter for this.

Please note, Today() and Now() throw errors, but GETDATE() works fine.

Comment: Does it help you to pass the '@BusinessDate' parameter as 'DATE' type from report to procedure, and then in procedure to add current time to the parameter? Or is it exactly what you've said in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), @BusinessDate, 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108))
```